# How to open cache on failed mysql connection?

Tags: php, html, mysql, caching, connection

I connect to MySQL to fetch data for dynamic content for my site. But in case my remote database server is down, how can I show visitors a webpage cache or replacement instead?

My current attempt is to load the page from my remote FTP server. I would instantiate a class that attempts to connect to the database:

```
        public function __construct($cached)
    {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $data);

        // if we cannot open a connection to mysql then use ftp
        if (! $this->con)
        {
            fopen("ftp://" . $ftpuser . ":" . $ftppass . "@" . $ftpserv . $cached, "r");

            return;
        }

        mysql_select_db($data, $this->con);
    }
```

Something fails at

```
fopen(...)
```

and the page wouldn't have the data as when the server is up. However, I tested the enclosed string and it works.

How can I fix this attempt or what's the best solution for my issue in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

```
        $obj = file_get_contents("ftp://" . $ftpuser . ":" . $ftppass . "@" . $ftpserv . $dir, "r");

    echo $obj;
```

I used

```
file_get_contents()
```

and echoed an entire page.